# compute the total of 3 table using union

Tags: sql

Good day,

I just want to query regarding my query,

i want to get the sum of each table with single country
here is my table and desired output

here is my query

```
        select country,continent,(mycol2+mycol3+mycol4+mycol5+mycol6+mycol7+mycol8
   +mycol9+mycol10+mycol11+mycol12+mycol13+mycol14+mycol15+mycol16+mycol17
   +mycol18+mycol19+mycol20+mycol21+mycol22+mycol23+mycol14+mycol25+mycol26
   +mycol27+mycol27+mycol29+mycol30+mycol31) as total from tblWRSTopTargetVictim
        union 
        select country,continent,(mycol2+mycol3+mycol4+mycol5+mycol6+mycol7+mycol8
   +mycol9+mycol10+mycol11+mycol12+mycol13+mycol14+mycol15+mycol16+mycol17
   +mycol18+mycol19+mycol20+mycol21+mycol22+mycol23+mycol14+mycol25+mycol26
   +mycol27+mycol27+mycol29+mycol30+mycol31) as total from               tblFRSMalwareDetectionMap
        union 
        select country,continent,(mycol2+mycol3+mycol4+mycol5+mycol6+mycol7+mycol8
   +mycol9+mycol10+mycol11+mycol12+mycol13+mycol14+mycol15+mycol16+mycol17
   +mycol18+mycol19+mycol20+mycol21+mycol22+mycol23+mycol14+mycol25+mycol26
   +mycol27+mycol27+mycol29+mycol30+mycol31) as total from tblERSSpamVolumeMap
```

here is the generated result based on the query above,i want to compute for the result of total per country below is the result that i want to view

```
     country        continent       total
     AFGHANISTAN    Asia            6871
    AFGHANISTAN Asia            61479
    AFGHANISTAN Asia            257988
    ALAND ISLANDS   Europe          19
    ALAND ISLANDS   Europe          201
    ALBANIA         Europe          2340
    ALBANIA         Europe          9998
    ALBANIA         Europe          2612205
    ALGERIA         Africa          5675
    ALGERIA         Africa          84028
    ALGERIA         Africa          1435598
    AMERICAN        SAMOA   Oceania 8
    AMERICAN        SAMOA   Oceania 538
    AMERICAN        SAMOA   Oceania 43325
    ANDORRA         Europe          1341
    ANDORRA         Europe          3330
    ANDORRA         Europe          91466
    ANGOLA          Africa          8211
    ANGOLA          Africa          30009
    ANGOLA          Africa          846688
    ANGUILLA    North America   313
    ANGUILLA    North America   919
```

and i want the output is

```
     country        continent          total
     AFGHANISTAN    Asia               326338
     ALAND ISLANDS  Europe             40
     ALBANIA        Europe             12338
     ALGERIA    Africa             1525301
     AMERICAN       SAMOA   Oceania    43871
     ANDORRA        EUROPE             96137
     ANGOLA         AFRICA             884908
     ........
     ........
```

Comment: Provide DB schema, sample data, expected output (formatted, not just a description). If you want generic help, use "GROUP BY country" to group by the country

Comment: country        Continent        total

Comment: country continent total            AFGHANISTAN Asia 6871
AFGHANISTAN Asia 61479
AFGHANISTAN Asia 257988
ALAND ISLANDS Europe 19
ALAND ISLANDS Europe 201
ALBANIA Europe 2340
ALBANIA Europe 9998
ALBANIA Europe 2612205
ALGERIA Africa 5675
ALGERIA Africa 84028
ALGERIA Africa 1435598
ALL All 1636185828
AMERICAN SAMOA Oceania 8
AMERICAN SAMOA Oceania 538
AMERICAN SAMOA Oceania 43325
ANDORRA Europe 1341
ANDORRA Europe 3330
ANDORRA Europe 91466
ANGOLA Africa 8211
ANGOLA Africa 30009
ANGOLA Africa 846688
all i want is to compute the total per country

Comment: I give up, I think you misunderstood my request for more information and just answered something, out of context. Either you give more information or this question will go unanswered/ or answered with a guess. I suggest to provide a "CREATE TABLE" that creates the table you are using "INSERT INTO" that will place data inside it.

Comment: Did you try "GROUP BY" ? do you know what it does? it groups by a column, so do a SUM((mycol2+mycol3+mycol4+mycol5+mycol6+mycol7+mycol8+mycol9+mycol10+mycol11+mycol12+mycol13+mycol14+mycol15+mycol16+mycol17+mycol18+mycol19+mycol20+mycol21+mycol22+mycol23+mycol14+mycol25+mycol26+mycol27+mycol27+mycol29+mycol30+mycol31)) and GROUP BY country and it should work (though I have no way to check)

Comment: @nrauthaus, yes i already group my query by country, but it only group it i just want to see a single country and have total for that country

Comment: @CyberDaemon how is GROUP BY not working out for you? It should be exactly what you need, seems like a really simple (allthough massive, textwise) query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to use a group by. However, I can understand how it is not immediately obvious how to do that:

```
SELECT country, continent, sum(total)
 FROM (
select country,continent,(mycol2+mycol3+mycol4+mycol5+mycol6+mycol7+mycol8   +mycol9+mycol10+mycol11+mycol12+mycol13+mycol14+mycol15+mycol16+mycol17   +mycol18+mycol19+mycol20+mycol21+mycol22+mycol23+mycol14+mycol25+mycol26   +mycol27+mycol27+mycol29+mycol30+mycol31) as total 
 from tblWRSTopTargetVictim
    union all
select country,continent,(mycol2+mycol3+mycol4+mycol5+mycol6+mycol7+mycol8   +mycol9+mycol10+mycol11+mycol12+mycol13+mycol14+mycol15+mycol16+mycol17   +mycol18+mycol19+mycol20+mycol21+mycol22+mycol23+mycol14+mycol25+mycol26   +mycol27+mycol27+mycol29+mycol30+mycol31) as total 
 from tblFRSMalwareDetectionMap
    union all
select country,continent,(mycol2+mycol3+mycol4+mycol5+mycol6+mycol7+mycol8   +mycol9+mycol10+mycol11+mycol12+mycol13+mycol14+mycol15+mycol16+mycol17   +mycol18+mycol19+mycol20+mycol21+mycol22+mycol23+mycol14+mycol25+mycol26   +mycol27+mycol27+mycol29+mycol30+mycol31) as total 
 from tblERSSpamVolumeMap
     ) as A
 GROUP BY country, continent
```